# WiX Toolset MSI upgrade results in missing files after reboot

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have a Wix Toolset based installer. When I do an upgrade from one MSI to another and having specific files locked in a specific way, the installer ends rebooting the machine to replace the locked files. That is all fine, but after the reboot, the locked files are missing, they have not been replaced with the ones contained in the new MSI.

In more detail, the scenario is as follows:

- Version 1.0.0 is installed.
- One of the installed programs are run causing some files to be locked.
- Version 1.0.1 is installed. This results in a log statement like "Info 1903.Scheduling reboot operation" followed by "Windows Installer requires a system restart".
- The machine is rebooted.

Now the files associated with the "Info 1903" messages are missing from the system and the installation is in a non-working state. And the exit code from the installer does not indicate any error.

In real life, the locking is performed by a virus scanner that I have no control over, and it is not a process I can kill. I have made a sample project that reproduces the problem (not with the virus scanner, but with a subset of a JRE that just happens to be able to reproduce the problem), it can be downloaded from:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/bi5dfkozqmhwqac/WixUgradeMissingFilesAfterReboot.zip?dl=0

To reproduce the issue (Windows 2012 R2 (or Windows 8.1) + Windows Installer 5):

- Build the project and install the MSI (msiexec /i SomeProduct.msi /quiet /l* log1.txt)
- Change the version number in Project.wixproj
- Run c:\Program Files (x86)\SomeCompany\SomeProduct\Jre\bin\rmiregistry.exe from a *remote* machine (if run locally, the restart manager will detect it and the problem will not be present)
- Build the project and install the new MSI (msiexec /i SomeProduct.msi /quiet /l* log2.txt)
- Wait for the machine to reboot
- Try to run rmiregistry.exe again; that fails since two jar files in c:\Program Files (x86)\SomeCompany\SomeProduct\Jre\lib are missing!!!

If it is not clear from the above, my problem is that my installation gets into a non-working state and I receive no error code that indicates that I have a problem! Please help!

log1.txt:

```
=== Logging started: 12-10-2017  08:29:15 ===
Action start 08:29:15: INSTALL.
Action start 08:29:15: FindRelatedProducts.
Action ended 08:29:15: FindRelatedProducts. Return value 1.
Action start 08:29:15: LaunchConditions.
Action ended 08:29:15: LaunchConditions. Return value 1.
Action start 08:29:15: ValidateProductID.
Action ended 08:29:15: ValidateProductID. Return value 1.
Action start 08:29:15: CostInitialize.
Action ended 08:29:15: CostInitialize. Return value 1.
Action start 08:29:15: FileCost.
Action ended 08:29:15: FileCost. Return value 1.
Action start 08:29:15: CostFinalize.
Action ended 08:29:15: CostFinalize. Return value 1.
Action start 08:29:15: MigrateFeatureStates.
Action ended 08:29:15: MigrateFeatureStates. Return value 0.
Action start 08:29:15: InstallValidate.
Action ended 08:29:15: InstallValidate. Return value 1.
Action start 08:29:15: InstallInitialize.
Action ended 08:29:15: InstallInitialize. Return value 1.
Action start 08:29:15: RemoveExistingProducts.
Action ended 08:29:15: RemoveExistingProducts. Return value 1.
Action start 08:29:15: ProcessComponents.
Action ended 08:29:15: ProcessComponents. Return value 1.
Action start 08:29:15: UnpublishFeatures.
Action ended 08:29:15: UnpublishFeatures. Return value 1.
Action start 08:29:15: RemoveFiles.
Action ended 08:29:15: RemoveFiles. Return value 0.
Action start 08:29:15: InstallFiles.
Action ended 08:29:15: InstallFiles. Return value 1.
Action start 08:29:15: RegisterUser.
Action ended 08:29:15: RegisterUser. Return value 1.
Action start 08:29:15: RegisterProduct.
Action ended 08:29:15: RegisterProduct. Return value 1.
Action start 08:29:15: PublishFeatures.
Action ended 08:29:15: PublishFeatures. Return value 1.
Action start 08:29:15: PublishProduct.
Action ended 08:29:15: PublishProduct. Return value 1.
Action start 08:29:15: InstallFinalize.
Action ended 08:29:16: InstallFinalize. Return value 1.
Action ended 08:29:16: INSTALL. Return value 1.
Property(S): UpgradeCode = {40C1BE8C-35A3-41B6-8F30-5D5D8B87CDCB}
Property(S): JreBin = C:\Program Files (x86)\SomeCompany\SomeProduct\Jre\bin\
Property(S): JreBinServer = C:\Program Files (x86)\SomeCompany\SomeProduct\Jre\bin\server\
Property(S): JreLib = C:\Program Files (x86)\SomeCompany\SomeProduct\Jre\lib\
Property(S): JreLibAmd64 = C:\Program Files (x86)\SomeCompany\SomeProduct\Jre\lib\amd64\
Property(S): JreFolder = C:\Program Files (x86)\SomeCompany\SomeProduct\Jre\
Property(S): INSTALL_FOLDER = C:\Program Files (x86)\SomeCompany\SomeProduct\
Property(S): CompanyFolder = C:\Program Files (x86)\SomeCompany\
Property(S): ProgramFilesFolder = C:\Program Files (x86)\
Property(S): TARGETDIR = C:\
Property(S): SourceDir = C:\tmp\
Property(S): Manufacturer = SomeCompany
Property(S): ProductCode = {4FCBADA8-8B3C-43F7-A5A1-45F3F620DE8E}
Property(S): ProductLanguage = 1033
Property(S): ProductName = SomeProduct 1.1.0
Property(S): ProductVersion = 1.1.0
Property(S): SecureCustomProperties = WIX_DOWNGRADE_DETECTED;WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED
Property(S): MsiLogFileLocation = C:\tmp\log1.txt
Property(S): PackageCode = {EB8F095B-7618-450A-86B2-E96F54B68555}
Property(S): ProductState = -1
Property(S): PackagecodeChanging = 1
Property(S): CURRENTDIRECTORY = C:\tmp
Property(S): CLIENTUILEVEL = 3
Property(S): CLIENTPROCESSID = 852
Property(S): VersionDatabase = 100
Property(S): VersionMsi = 5.00
Property(S): VersionNT = 603
Property(S): VersionNT64 = 603
Property(S): WindowsBuild = 9600
Property(S): ServicePackLevel = 0
Property(S): ServicePackLevelMinor = 0
Property(S): MsiNTProductType = 2
Property(S): WindowsFolder = C:\Windows\
Property(S): WindowsVolume = C:\
Property(S): System64Folder = C:\Windows\system32\
Property(S): SystemFolder = C:\Windows\SysWOW64\
Property(S): RemoteAdminTS = 1
Property(S): TempFolder = C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\
Property(S): CommonFilesFolder = C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\
Property(S): ProgramFiles64Folder = C:\Program Files\
Property(S): CommonFiles64Folder = C:\Program Files\Common Files\
Property(S): AppDataFolder = C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\
Property(S): FavoritesFolder = C:\Users\Administrator\Favorites\
Property(S): NetHoodFolder = C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts\
Property(S): PersonalFolder = C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\
Property(S): PrintHoodFolder = C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Printer Shortcuts\
Property(S): RecentFolder = C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\
Property(S): SendToFolder = C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo\
Property(S): TemplateFolder = C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Templates\
Property(S): CommonAppDataFolder = C:\ProgramData\
Property(S): LocalAppDataFolder = C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\
Property(S): MyPicturesFolder = C:\Users\Administrator\Pictures\
Property(S): AdminToolsFolder = C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools\
Property(S): StartupFolder = C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\
Property(S): ProgramMenuFolder = C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\
Property(S): StartMenuFolder = C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\
Property(S): DesktopFolder = C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\
Property(S): FontsFolder = C:\Windows\Fonts\
Property(S): GPTSupport = 1
Property(S): OLEAdvtSupport = 1
Property(S): ShellAdvtSupport = 1
Property(S): MsiAMD64 = 6
Property(S): Msix64 = 6
Property(S): Intel = 6
Property(S): PhysicalMemory = 6071
Property(S): VirtualMemory = 6003
Property(S): AdminUser = 1
Property(S): MsiTrueAdminUser = 1
Property(S): LogonUser = Administrator
Property(S): UserSID = S-1-5-21-2265845470-1617532221-1463728152-500
Property(S): UserLanguageID = 1030
Property(S): ComputerName = WIN-6FTE5M0IU82
Property(S): SystemLanguageID = 1030
Property(S): ScreenX = 1024
Property(S): ScreenY = 768
Property(S): CaptionHeight = 23
Property(S): BorderTop = 1
Property(S): BorderSide = 1
Property(S): TextHeight = 16
Property(S): TextInternalLeading = 3
Property(S): ColorBits = 32
Property(S): TTCSupport = 1
Property(S): Time = 08:29:16
Property(S): Date = 12-10-2017
Property(S): MsiNetAssemblySupport = 4.0.30319.33440
Property(S): MsiWin32AssemblySupport = 6.3.9600.17415
Property(S): RedirectedDllSupport = 2
Property(S): MsiRunningElevated = 1
Property(S): Privileged = 1
Property(S): USERNAME = Windows User
Property(S): DATABASE = C:\Windows\Installer\2a222.msi
Property(S): OriginalDatabase = C:\tmp\SomeProduct.msi
Property(S): UILevel = 2
Property(S): ACTION = INSTALL
Property(S): ROOTDRIVE = C:\
Property(S): CostingComplete = 1
Property(S): OutOfDiskSpace = 0
Property(S): OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0
Property(S): PrimaryVolumeSpaceAvailable = 0
Property(S): PrimaryVolumeSpaceRequired = 0
Property(S): PrimaryVolumeSpaceRemaining = 0
Property(S): INSTALLLEVEL = 1
Property(S): SOURCEDIR = C:\tmp\
Property(S): SourcedirProduct = {4FCBADA8-8B3C-43F7-A5A1-45F3F620DE8E}
Property(S): ProductToBeRegistered = 1
MSI (s) (C4:FC) [08:29:16:614]: Product: SomeProduct 1.1.0 -- Installation completed successfully.

MSI (s) (C4:FC) [08:29:16:614]: Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: SomeProduct 1.1.0. Product Version: 1.1.0. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: SomeCompany. Installation success or error status: 0.

=== Logging stopped: 12-10-2017  08:29:16 ===
```

log2.txt:

```
=== Logging started: 12-10-2017  08:31:37 ===
Action start 08:31:37: INSTALL.
Action start 08:31:37: FindRelatedProducts.
Action ended 08:31:37: FindRelatedProducts. Return value 1.
Action start 08:31:37: LaunchConditions.
Action ended 08:31:37: LaunchConditions. Return value 1.
Action start 08:31:37: ValidateProductID.
Action ended 08:31:37: ValidateProductID. Return value 1.
Action start 08:31:37: CostInitialize.
Action ended 08:31:37: CostInitialize. Return value 1.
Action start 08:31:37: FileCost.
Action ended 08:31:37: FileCost. Return value 1.
Action start 08:31:37: CostFinalize.
Action ended 08:31:37: CostFinalize. Return value 1.
Action start 08:31:37: MigrateFeatureStates.
Action ended 08:31:37: MigrateFeatureStates. Return value 1.
Action start 08:31:37: InstallValidate.
Action ended 08:31:37: InstallValidate. Return value 1.
Action start 08:31:37: InstallInitialize.
Action ended 08:31:37: InstallInitialize. Return value 1.
Action start 08:31:37: RemoveExistingProducts.
Action start 08:31:37: INSTALL.
Action start 08:31:37: FindRelatedProducts.
Action ended 08:31:37: FindRelatedProducts. Return value 0.
Action start 08:31:37: LaunchConditions.
Action ended 08:31:37: LaunchConditions. Return value 1.
Action start 08:31:37: ValidateProductID.
Action ended 08:31:37: ValidateProductID. Return value 1.
Action start 08:31:37: CostInitialize.
Action ended 08:31:37: CostInitialize. Return value 1.
Action start 08:31:37: FileCost.
Action ended 08:31:37: FileCost. Return value 1.
Action start 08:31:37: CostFinalize.
Action ended 08:31:37: CostFinalize. Return value 1.
Action start 08:31:37: MigrateFeatureStates.
Action ended 08:31:37: MigrateFeatureStates. Return value 0.
Action start 08:31:37: InstallValidate.
Action ended 08:31:37: InstallValidate. Return value 1.
Action start 08:31:37: InstallInitialize.
Action ended 08:31:37: InstallInitialize. Return value 1.
Action start 08:31:37: RemoveExistingProducts.
Action ended 08:31:37: RemoveExistingProducts. Return value 0.
Action start 08:31:37: ProcessComponents.
Action ended 08:31:37: ProcessComponents. Return value 1.
Action start 08:31:37: UnpublishFeatures.
Action ended 08:31:37: UnpublishFeatures. Return value 1.
Action start 08:31:37: RemoveFiles.
Action ended 08:31:37: RemoveFiles. Return value 0.
Action start 08:31:37: InstallFiles.
Action ended 08:31:37: InstallFiles. Return value 1.
Action start 08:31:37: RegisterUser.
Action ended 08:31:37: RegisterUser. Return value 0.
Action start 08:31:37: RegisterProduct.
Action ended 08:31:37: RegisterProduct. Return value 1.
Action start 08:31:37: PublishFeatures.
Action ended 08:31:37: PublishFeatures. Return value 1.
Action start 08:31:37: PublishProduct.
Action ended 08:31:37: PublishProduct. Return value 1.
Action start 08:31:37: InstallFinalize.
Info 1903.Scheduling reboot operation: Deleting file C:\Program Files (x86)\SomeCompany\SomeProduct\Jre\lib\jsse.jar. Must reboot to complete operation.
Info 1903.Scheduling reboot operation: Deleting file C:\Program Files (x86)\SomeCompany\SomeProduct\Jre\lib\rt.jar. Must reboot to complete operation.
Action ended 08:31:37: InstallFinalize. Return value 1.
Action ended 08:31:37: INSTALL. Return value 1.
Property(N): UpgradeCode = {40C1BE8C-35A3-41B6-8F30-5D5D8B87CDCB}
Property(N): JreBin = C:\Program Files (x86)\SomeCompany\SomeProduct\Jre\bin\
Property(N): JreBinServer = C:\Program Files (x86)\SomeCompany\SomeProduct\Jre\bin\server\
Property(N): JreLib = C:\Program Files (x86)\SomeCompany\SomeProduct\Jre\lib\
Property(N): JreLibAmd64 = C:\Program Files (x86)\SomeCompany\SomeProduct\Jre\lib\amd64\
Property(N): JreFolder = C:\Program Files (x86)\SomeCompany\SomeProduct\Jre\
Property(N): INSTALL_FOLDER = C:\Program Files (x86)\SomeCompany\SomeProduct\
Property(N): CompanyFolder = C:\Program Files (x86)\SomeCompany\
Property(N): ProgramFilesFolder = C:\Program Files (x86)\
Property(N): TARGETDIR = C:\
Property(N): Manufacturer = SomeCompany
Property(N): ProductCode = {4FCBADA8-8B3C-43F7-A5A1-45F3F620DE8E}
Property(N): ProductLanguage = 1033
Property(N): ProductName = SomeProduct 1.1.0
Property(N): ProductVersion = 1.1.0
Property(N): SecureCustomProperties = WIX_DOWNGRADE_DETECTED;WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED
Property(N): PackageCode = {EB8F095B-7618-450A-86B2-E96F54B68555}
Property(N): ProductState = 5
Property(N): UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE = {5C3E5D66-D7F0-4EF6-BFEE-E9811820258F}
Property(N): CLIENTPROCESSID = 2660
Property(N): CLIENTUILEVEL = 3
Property(N): REMOVE = ALL
Property(N): PRODUCTLANGUAGE = 1033
Property(N): VersionDatabase = 100
Property(N): VersionMsi = 5.00
Property(N): VersionNT = 603
Property(N): VersionNT64 = 603
Property(N): WindowsBuild = 9600
Property(N): ServicePackLevel = 0
Property(N): ServicePackLevelMinor = 0
Property(N): MsiNTProductType = 2
Property(N): WindowsFolder = C:\Windows\
Property(N): WindowsVolume = C:\
Property(N): System64Folder = C:\Windows\system32\
Property(N): SystemFolder = C:\Windows\SysWOW64\
Property(N): RemoteAdminTS = 1
Property(N): TempFolder = C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\
Property(N): CommonFilesFolder = C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\
Property(N): ProgramFiles64Folder = C:\Program Files\
Property(N): CommonFiles64Folder = C:\Program Files\Common Files\
Property(N): AppDataFolder = C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\
Property(N): FavoritesFolder = C:\Users\Administrator\Favorites\
Property(N): NetHoodFolder = C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts\
Property(N): PersonalFolder = C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\
Property(N): PrintHoodFolder = C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Printer Shortcuts\
Property(N): RecentFolder = C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\
Property(N): SendToFolder = C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo\
Property(N): TemplateFolder = C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Templates\
Property(N): CommonAppDataFolder = C:\ProgramData\
Property(N): LocalAppDataFolder = C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\
Property(N): MyPicturesFolder = C:\Users\Administrator\Pictures\
Property(N): AdminToolsFolder = C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools\
Property(N): StartupFolder = C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\
Property(N): ProgramMenuFolder = C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\
Property(N): StartMenuFolder = C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\
Property(N): DesktopFolder = C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\
Property(N): FontsFolder = C:\Windows\Fonts\
Property(N): GPTSupport = 1
Property(N): OLEAdvtSupport = 1
Property(N): ShellAdvtSupport = 1
Property(N): MsiAMD64 = 6
Property(N): Msix64 = 6
Property(N): Intel = 6
Property(N): PhysicalMemory = 6071
Property(N): VirtualMemory = 6006
Property(N): AdminUser = 1
Property(N): MsiTrueAdminUser = 1
Property(N): LogonUser = Administrator
Property(N): UserSID = S-1-5-21-2265845470-1617532221-1463728152-500
Property(N): UserLanguageID = 1030
Property(N): ComputerName = WIN-6FTE5M0IU82
Property(N): SystemLanguageID = 1030
Property(N): ScreenX = 1024
Property(N): ScreenY = 768
Property(N): CaptionHeight = 23
Property(N): BorderTop = 1
Property(N): BorderSide = 1
Property(N): TextHeight = 16
Property(N): TextInternalLeading = 3
Property(N): ColorBits = 32
Property(N): TTCSupport = 1
Property(N): Time = 08:31:37
Property(N): Date = 12-10-2017
Property(N): MsiNetAssemblySupport = 4.0.30319.33440
Property(N): MsiWin32AssemblySupport = 6.3.9600.17415
Property(N): RedirectedDllSupport = 2
Property(N): MsiRunningElevated = 1
Property(N): Privileged = 1
Property(N): USERNAME = Windows User
Property(N): Installed = 00:00:00
Property(N): DATABASE = C:\Windows\Installer\2a225.msi
Property(N): OriginalDatabase = C:\Windows\Installer\2a225.msi
Property(N): UILevel = 2
Property(N): Preselected = 1
Property(N): ACTION = INSTALL
Property(N): ROOTDRIVE = C:\
Property(N): CostingComplete = 1
Property(N): OutOfDiskSpace = 0
Property(N): OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0
Property(N): PrimaryVolumeSpaceAvailable = 0
Property(N): PrimaryVolumeSpaceRequired = 0
Property(N): PrimaryVolumeSpaceRemaining = 0
Property(N): INSTALLLEVEL = 1
MSI (s) (C4:04) [08:31:37:489]: Windows Installer requires a system restart. Product Name: SomeProduct 1.1.0. Product Version: 1.1.0. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: SomeCompany. Type of System Restart: 1. Reason for Restart: 1.

Property(N): ReplacedInUseFiles = 1
CustomAction  returned actual error code -1 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
Action ended 08:31:37: RemoveExistingProducts. Return value 1.
Action start 08:31:37: ProcessComponents.
Action ended 08:31:37: ProcessComponents. Return value 1.
Action start 08:31:37: UnpublishFeatures.
Action ended 08:31:37: UnpublishFeatures. Return value 1.
Action start 08:31:37: RemoveFiles.
Action ended 08:31:37: RemoveFiles. Return value 0.
Action start 08:31:37: InstallFiles.
Action ended 08:31:37: InstallFiles. Return value 1.
Action start 08:31:37: RegisterUser.
Action ended 08:31:37: RegisterUser. Return value 1.
Action start 08:31:37: RegisterProduct.
Action ended 08:31:37: RegisterProduct. Return value 1.
Action start 08:31:37: PublishFeatures.
Action ended 08:31:37: PublishFeatures. Return value 1.
Action start 08:31:37: PublishProduct.
Action ended 08:31:37: PublishProduct. Return value 1.
Action start 08:31:37: InstallFinalize.
Action ended 08:31:38: InstallFinalize. Return value 1.
Action ended 08:31:38: INSTALL. Return value 1.
You must restart your system for the configuration changes made to SomeProduct 1.2.0 to take effect. Click Yes to restart now or No if you plan to manually restart later.
Property(S): UpgradeCode = {40C1BE8C-35A3-41B6-8F30-5D5D8B87CDCB}
Property(S): JreBin = C:\Program Files (x86)\SomeCompany\SomeProduct\Jre\bin\
Property(S): JreBinServer = C:\Program Files (x86)\SomeCompany\SomeProduct\Jre\bin\server\
Property(S): JreLib = C:\Program Files (x86)\SomeCompany\SomeProduct\Jre\lib\
Property(S): JreLibAmd64 = C:\Program Files (x86)\SomeCompany\SomeProduct\Jre\lib\amd64\
Property(S): JreFolder = C:\Program Files (x86)\SomeCompany\SomeProduct\Jre\
Property(S): INSTALL_FOLDER = C:\Program Files (x86)\SomeCompany\SomeProduct\
Property(S): CompanyFolder = C:\Program Files (x86)\SomeCompany\
Property(S): ProgramFilesFolder = C:\Program Files (x86)\
Property(S): TARGETDIR = C:\
Property(S): SourceDir = C:\tmp\
Property(S): Manufacturer = SomeCompany
Property(S): ProductCode = {5C3E5D66-D7F0-4EF6-BFEE-E9811820258F}
Property(S): ProductLanguage = 1033
Property(S): ProductName = SomeProduct 1.2.0
Property(S): ProductVersion = 1.2.0
Property(S): SecureCustomProperties = WIX_DOWNGRADE_DETECTED;WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED
Property(S): WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED = {4FCBADA8-8B3C-43F7-A5A1-45F3F620DE8E}
Property(S): MsiLogFileLocation = C:\tmp\log2.txt
Property(S): PackageCode = {38ECAF6B-3C6B-4FEB-8148-EE6FBA44A659}
Property(S): ProductState = -1
Property(S): PackagecodeChanging = 1
Property(S): CURRENTDIRECTORY = C:\tmp
Property(S): CLIENTUILEVEL = 3
Property(S): CLIENTPROCESSID = 2660
Property(S): VersionDatabase = 100
Property(S): VersionMsi = 5.00
Property(S): VersionNT = 603
Property(S): VersionNT64 = 603
Property(S): WindowsBuild = 9600
Property(S): ServicePackLevel = 0
Property(S): ServicePackLevelMinor = 0
Property(S): MsiNTProductType = 2
Property(S): WindowsFolder = C:\Windows\
Property(S): WindowsVolume = C:\
Property(S): System64Folder = C:\Windows\system32\
Property(S): SystemFolder = C:\Windows\SysWOW64\
Property(S): RemoteAdminTS = 1
Property(S): TempFolder = C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\
Property(S): CommonFilesFolder = C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\
Property(S): ProgramFiles64Folder = C:\Program Files\
Property(S): CommonFiles64Folder = C:\Program Files\Common Files\
Property(S): AppDataFolder = C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\
Property(S): FavoritesFolder = C:\Users\Administrator\Favorites\
Property(S): NetHoodFolder = C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts\
Property(S): PersonalFolder = C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\
Property(S): PrintHoodFolder = C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Printer Shortcuts\
Property(S): RecentFolder = C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\
Property(S): SendToFolder = C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo\
Property(S): TemplateFolder = C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Templates\
Property(S): CommonAppDataFolder = C:\ProgramData\
Property(S): LocalAppDataFolder = C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\
Property(S): MyPicturesFolder = C:\Users\Administrator\Pictures\
Property(S): AdminToolsFolder = C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools\
Property(S): StartupFolder = C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\
Property(S): ProgramMenuFolder = C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\
Property(S): StartMenuFolder = C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\
Property(S): DesktopFolder = C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\
Property(S): FontsFolder = C:\Windows\Fonts\
Property(S): GPTSupport = 1
Property(S): OLEAdvtSupport = 1
Property(S): ShellAdvtSupport = 1
Property(S): MsiAMD64 = 6
Property(S): Msix64 = 6
Property(S): Intel = 6
Property(S): PhysicalMemory = 6071
Property(S): VirtualMemory = 6007
Property(S): AdminUser = 1
Property(S): MsiTrueAdminUser = 1
Property(S): LogonUser = Administrator
Property(S): UserSID = S-1-5-21-2265845470-1617532221-1463728152-500
Property(S): UserLanguageID = 1030
Property(S): ComputerName = WIN-6FTE5M0IU82
Property(S): SystemLanguageID = 1030
Property(S): ScreenX = 1024
Property(S): ScreenY = 768
Property(S): CaptionHeight = 23
Property(S): BorderTop = 1
Property(S): BorderSide = 1
Property(S): TextHeight = 16
Property(S): TextInternalLeading = 3
Property(S): ColorBits = 32
Property(S): TTCSupport = 1
Property(S): Time = 08:31:38
Property(S): Date = 12-10-2017
Property(S): MsiNetAssemblySupport = 4.0.30319.33440
Property(S): MsiWin32AssemblySupport = 6.3.9600.17415
Property(S): RedirectedDllSupport = 2
Property(S): MsiRunningElevated = 1
Property(S): Privileged = 1
Property(S): USERNAME = Windows User
Property(S): DATABASE = C:\Windows\Installer\2a226.msi
Property(S): OriginalDatabase = C:\tmp\SomeProduct.msi
Property(S): UILevel = 2
Property(S): ACTION = INSTALL
Property(S): MIGRATE = {4FCBADA8-8B3C-43F7-A5A1-45F3F620DE8E}
Property(S): ROOTDRIVE = C:\
Property(S): CostingComplete = 1
Property(S): OutOfDiskSpace = 0
Property(S): OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0
Property(S): PrimaryVolumeSpaceAvailable = 0
Property(S): PrimaryVolumeSpaceRequired = 0
Property(S): PrimaryVolumeSpaceRemaining = 0
Property(S): INSTALLLEVEL = 1
Property(S): SOURCEDIR = C:\tmp\
Property(S): SourcedirProduct = {5C3E5D66-D7F0-4EF6-BFEE-E9811820258F}
Property(S): ProductToBeRegistered = 1
MSI (s) (C4:FC) [08:31:38:271]: Product: SomeProduct 1.2.0 -- Installation completed successfully.

MSI (s) (C4:FC) [08:31:38:271]: Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: SomeProduct 1.2.0. Product Version: 1.2.0. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: SomeCompany. Installation success or error status: 0.

MSI (s) (C4:FC) [08:31:38:271]: Windows Installer requires a system restart. Product Name: SomeProduct 1.2.0. Product Version: 1.2.0. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: SomeCompany. Type of System Restart: 1. Reason for Restart: 0.

=== Logging stopped: 12-10-2017  08:31:38 ===
```

Comment: If you have an entire verbose log of the upgrade then please post it.

Comment: Added log files and clarified that the program has to be run from a remote machine to provoke the problem.